# How to export result of SQL query into csv-style formatted string, that will be later saved into clob in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem:
I have a table Source_Data(actually, quite many different source tables), and I need to export some data from them into Result_Table. For each source table I have some sql that returns the data, and it needs to be transformed into csv-like string.

For example, Source_Data1 table has PK - ID, some foreign keys - A_ID, B_ID, CREATION_DATE date, and some other columns.

I need to export the result of SQL query that selects data from Source_Data1 table, it usually returns the primary key, some foreign keys which are not null and a date which is also not null, and transform it into cvs-like string, which should be saved later in some other table as a clob.

```
CREATE TABLE Source_Data1 (
    ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    A_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
    B_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
    CREATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
    some other columns );
```

and I have SQL query:

```
select ID, A_ID, B_ID, CREATION_DATE
from Source_Data1
where <expression>
```

Based on this query, I need to generate string like this:

```
'ID,A_ID,B_ID,CREATION_DATE
1,200,10,2018-03-01 00:00:00.0
7,202,11,2018-03-02 00:00:00.0
8,205,11,2018-03-02 00:00:00.0'
```

and I need to save it into the Result table as a clob:

```
Insert into Result_Table (ID, SOURCE_NAME, DATA) values         
(result_seq.nextval, 'Source_Data1', result of sqlquery 1);
```

And this needs to be done for many source tables.

I was wondering if there is some general way to do it? Because for each source table I have its own sql query, different set of selected columns, and generating this csv string manually looks not very nice.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 should be to download [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html), you can easily save the output of SQL select statements in CSV format via "SET SQLFORMAT CSV" and SPOOL, it does the work for you. So you can use that to loop through a bunch of table names / select statements, spool and save the output of each to a directory via a shell script.

Next, here's a package that has a bunch of file utilities that all work with oracle DIRECTORY objects and the files within them. With this and some PL/SQL, you could easily pull those files that you've saved off into a table. There may be easier ways to do what you're trying to do, and if there is, I look forward to hearing about them for others. It's kind of a big problem to solve.

1) file_into_blob - To get the file into the database
2) convert_blob_to_clob  - To convert to clob
3) You can then insert that into your table.

Package spec

```
Create or replace package fileutils as

   --
   -- This procedure deletes a file, and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure delete_os_file (i_directory varchar2, i_filename varchar2);

   --
   -- This procedure moves and optionally renames a file, 
   -- and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure move_os_file ( i_source_directory in varchar2, i_source_file in varchar2, i_target_directory in varchar2, i_target_file in varchar2);

   --
   -- This procedure takes a blob variable and writes it to a file, 
   -- and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure blob_into_file (i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, i_blob in blob);

   --
   -- This procedure takes a file and uploads it into a blob variable
   -- and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure file_into_blob(i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, o_blob out blob);

   --
   -- This procedure converts a clob to a blob
   --
   Procedure convert_clob_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob);

   --
   -- This procedure converts a blob to a clob
   --
   Procedure convert_blob_to_clob (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob);

   --
   -- This one checks for file existence without Java
   --
   Function file_exists (i_directory in varchar2, i_filename in varchar2) return boolean;

   --
   -- Returns the basename of a filename
   -- Works with Windows and UNIX pathnames
   --
   Function basename (i_filename in varchar2) return varchar2;

   --
   -- This takes a Base64 string and converts it to a binary BLOB
   --
   Procedure base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob);
   Function base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob) return blob;

   --
   -- This takes a binary BLOB and converts it to a Base64 string
   --
   Procedure blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob);
   Function blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob) return clob;

End fileutils;
/

Show error;
```

Package body

```
Set define off;

Create or replace package body fileutils as

   Procedure delete_os_file (i_directory varchar2, i_filename varchar2)
   is

   Begin

      utl_file.fremove(i_directory,i_filename);

   End;

   Procedure move_os_file
   (
      i_source_directory     in varchar2,
      i_source_file          in varchar2,
      i_target_directory     in varchar2,
      i_target_file          in varchar2
   )

   is

      srcdir               varchar2(255) := upper(i_source_directory);
      tgtdir               varchar2(255) := upper(i_target_directory);

   begin

      --
      -- NOTE: If you're getting the all-too-familiar
      -- ORA-29292: file rename operation failed
      -- and you're SURE that your directory names are correct,
      -- and you're SURE that your privileges are correct, both at the
      -- OS level, and within the database, there's one last thing that
      -- can get you. I learned the hard way that this command will NOT
      -- work successfully renaming a file from one filesystem to another,
      -- at least when those filesystems are NFS mounted. That is all.
      --

      utl_file.frename(srcdir,i_source_file,tgtdir,i_target_file,TRUE);

   end move_os_file;

   Procedure blob_into_file (i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, i_blob in blob)
   is

      l_file            utl_file.file_type;
      l_buffer          raw(32767);
      l_amount          binary_integer := 32767;
      l_pos             integer := 1;
      i_blob_len        integer;

   Begin

      i_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(i_blob);
      l_pos:= 1;

      -- Open the destination file.
      l_file := utl_file.fopen(i_directory,i_file_name,'wb', 32767);

      -- Read chunks of the BLOB and write them to the file
      -- until complete.
      while l_pos < i_blob_len loop
         dbms_lob.read(i_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
         utl_file.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
         l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
      end loop;

      -- Close the file.
      utl_file.fclose(l_file);

   End blob_into_file;

   Procedure file_into_blob(i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, o_blob out blob) 
   is
      src_loc       bfile   := bfilename(i_directory, i_file_name);
   Begin

      -- Initialize the dest blob
      o_blob := empty_blob();

      -- Open source binary file from OS
      dbms_lob.open(src_loc, dbms_lob.lob_readonly);

      -- Create temporary LOB object
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(
            lob_loc => o_blob
          , cache   => true
          , dur     => dbms_lob.session
      );

      -- Open temporary lob
      dbms_lob.open(o_blob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);

      -- Load binary file into temporary LOB
      dbms_lob.loadfromfile(
            dest_lob => o_blob
          , src_lob  => src_loc
          , amount   => dbms_lob.getLength(src_loc));

      -- Close lob objects
      dbms_lob.close(o_blob);
      dbms_lob.close(src_loc);

   End file_into_blob;

   Function basename (i_filename in varchar2) return varchar2
   is
      v_basename        varchar2(1024);
   Begin

      --
      -- If the regex's below don't match, then it's already at its base name
      -- Return what was passed.
      --
      v_basename := i_filename;

      if regexp_like(i_filename,'^.*\\') then
         dbms_output.put_line('This is a Windows file');
         v_basename := regexp_substr(i_filename,'[^\]*$');
         dbms_output.put_line('Basename is : '||v_basename);
      end if;
      if regexp_like(i_filename,'^/') then
         dbms_output.put_line('This is a UNIX file');
         v_basename := regexp_substr(i_filename,'[^/]*$');
         dbms_output.put_line('Basename is : '||v_basename);
      end if;

      return v_basename;

   End basename;

   Function file_exists (i_directory in varchar2, i_filename in varchar2) return boolean
   is
      v_exists          boolean;
      v_file_length     number;
      v_block_size      number;
   Begin
      utl_file.fgetattr(upper(i_directory), i_filename, v_exists, v_file_length, v_block_size);   
      if (v_exists) then
         dbms_output.put_line('File '||i_filename||' exists, '||v_file_length||' bytes');
      else
         dbms_output.put_line('File '||i_filename||' does not exist');
      end if;

      return v_exists;

   end file_exists;

   Procedure convert_clob_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob)
   is

      v_in      pls_Integer := 1;
      v_out     pls_Integer := 1;
      v_lang    pls_Integer := 0;
      v_warning pls_Integer := 0;

   Begin

      dbms_lob.createtemporary(o_blob,TRUE);
      dbms_lob.converttoblob(o_blob,i_clob,DBMS_lob.getlength(i_clob),v_in,v_out,dbms_lob.default_csid,v_lang,v_warning);

   End convert_clob_to_blob;

   Procedure convert_blob_to_clob (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob)
   is

      v_in      pls_Integer := 1;
      v_out     pls_Integer := 1;
      v_lang    pls_Integer := 0;
      v_warning pls_Integer := 0;

   Begin

      dbms_lob.createtemporary(o_clob,TRUE);
      dbms_lob.converttoclob(o_clob,i_blob,DBMS_lob.getlength(i_blob),v_in,v_out,dbms_lob.default_csid,v_lang,v_warning);

   End convert_blob_to_clob;

   Procedure blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob)
   is

      v_out_cl     clob;
      file_len     pls_integer;
      modulo       pls_integer;
      pieces       pls_integer;
      amt          binary_integer      := 23808;
      buf          raw (32767);
      buf_tx       varchar2(32767);
      pos          pls_integer         := 1;
      filepos      pls_integer         := 1;
      counter      pls_integer         := 1;
   Begin
      dbms_lob.createtemporary (v_out_cl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      file_len := dbms_lob.getlength (i_blob);
      modulo := mod (file_len, amt);
      pieces := trunc (file_len / amt);

      while (counter <= pieces) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, amt, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
         filepos := counter * amt + 1;
         counter := counter + 1;
      end loop;

      if (modulo <> 0) THEN
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, modulo, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
      end if;

      o_clob := v_out_cl;

   End blob_to_base64_string;

   Function blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob) return clob
   is
      v_out_cl     clob;
      file_len     pls_integer;
      modulo       pls_integer;
      pieces       pls_integer;
      amt          binary_integer      := 23808;
      buf          raw (32767);
      buf_tx       varchar2(32767);
      pos          pls_integer         := 1;
      filepos      pls_integer         := 1;
      counter      pls_integer         := 1;
   Begin

      dbms_lob.createtemporary (v_out_cl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      file_len := dbms_lob.getlength (i_blob);
      modulo := mod (file_len, amt);
      pieces := trunc (file_len / amt);

      while (counter <= pieces) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, amt, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
         filepos := counter * amt + 1;
         counter := counter + 1;
      end loop;

      if (modulo <> 0) THEN
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, modulo, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
      end if;

      return v_out_cl;

   End blob_to_base64_string;

   Procedure base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob)
   is

      v_out_bl blob;
      clob_size number;
      pos number;
      charBuff varchar2(32767);
      dBuffer RAW(32767);
      v_readSize_nr number;
      v_line_nr number;

   begin
      dbms_lob.createTemporary (v_out_bl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      v_line_nr:=greatest(65, instr(i_clob,chr(10)), instr(i_clob,chr(13)));
      v_readSize_nr:= floor(32767/v_line_nr)*v_line_nr;
      clob_size := dbms_lob.getLength(i_clob);
      pos := 1;

      while (pos < clob_size) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_clob, v_readSize_nr, pos, charBuff);
         dBuffer := UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw(charBuff));
         dbms_lob.writeAppend (v_out_bl,utl_raw.length(dBuffer),dBuffer);
         pos := pos + v_readSize_nr;
      end loop;

      o_blob := v_out_bl;

   end base64_string_to_blob;

   Function  base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob) return blob
   is

      v_out_bl blob;
      clob_size number;
      pos number;
      charBuff varchar2(32767);
      dBuffer RAW(32767);
      v_readSize_nr number;
      v_line_nr number;

   begin
      dbms_lob.createTemporary (v_out_bl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      v_line_nr:=greatest(65, instr(i_clob,chr(10)), instr(i_clob,chr(13)));
      v_readSize_nr:= floor(32767/v_line_nr)*v_line_nr;
      clob_size := dbms_lob.getLength(i_clob);
      pos := 1;

      while (pos < clob_size) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_clob, v_readSize_nr, pos, charBuff);
         dBuffer := UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw(charBuff));
         dbms_lob.writeAppend (v_out_bl,utl_raw.length(dBuffer),dBuffer);
         pos := pos + v_readSize_nr;
      end loop;

      return v_out_bl;

   end base64_string_to_blob;

end fileutils;
/

Show error;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use LISTAGG function

```
select listagg(ONE_LINE) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROW_NUM)
  from (
        select 'ID,A_ID,B_ID,CREATION_DATE' || CHR(10) as ONE_LINE,
               -1 as ROW_NUM
          from dual
         union all
        select ID ||','|| A_ID ||','|| B_ID ||','|| CREATION_DATE || CHR(10) as ONE_LINE,
               ROWNUM as ROW_NUM
        from Source_Data1
        where <expression>
       );
```

Comment: i think it can be a good solution, but listagg has some limitations: Listagg function exceeding 4000 characters, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2548234

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a CSV version of a table as a CLOB row, using [`DATA_DUMP.SQL`](https://github.com/jonheller1/data_dump) and the function `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.READ2CLOB`.

First, install the `DATA_PUMP` procedure on your schema.  The program is a single command in a single file, you can run it through SQL*Plus or just copy and paste it into your IDE.

Next, create a directory on the server to temporarily store the files.  Most existing utilities are meant to create files.  It's easier to write a file and read it as a CLOB, than to modify the utility to write directly into a table.

```
create or replace directory temp_dir as 'C:\temp';
```

Then this PL/SQL block will read and write the data:

```
--Store a table as a single CSV clob.
--TODO: Delete the files from the server when done.
declare
    v_clob clob;
begin
    for tables in
    (
        --Query that returns the table names.
        --(Doesn't have to be hard-coded, maybe a query on DBA_TABLES would help?)
        select column_value table_name
        from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('source_data'))
    ) loop
        data_dump
        (
            query_in        => 'select * from source_data1',
            file_in         => 'source_data1.csv',
            directory_in    => 'temp_dir',
            nls_date_fmt_in => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
            delimiter_in    => ',',
            header_row_in    => true
        );

        v_clob := dbms_xslprocessor.read2clob
        (
            flocation => 'TEMP_DIR',
            fname     => 'source_data1.csv'
        );

        insert into result_table (id, source_name, data) values         
        (result_seq.nextval, 'source_data1', v_clob);

        --I wouldn't normally commit after each row, but when exporting large
        --tables the script may run too long and there's a good chance of an
        --error, so partial results may be helpful.
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Reading and writing to CSV files is not rocket science but it's not as trivial as most people think.  99% of the CSV programs out there can't handle things like commas in the data, or adding a header row.  So it's best to look for preexisting code instead of writing your own utility.

Comment: This looks very interesting and good, but unfortunately I have insufficient privileges to create any directories on the server that I work with, I wish it could write directly to the clob.