# Oracle - how to create csv string from query

Tags: oracle, csv, email

I need to create a csv string from a query to use it as parameter for a function that send email with attachment that wants file content as clob.

Let's say that example:

```
SELECT DESC,GROUP_COL, ID, CreatedDate  
FROM MyTABLE
```

I am looking for a method that can manage datetime format, string and any sort of contents without having to manage it manually.

Moreover I have no access to disk so conversion should be done directly in memory without using spool.

I read [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047937/how-to-export-result-of-sql-query-into-csv-style-formatted-string-that-will-be) but every posted solutions has limitations: as said cannot use file and LIST_AGG does not automatically manage string, date and so on

[even that](http://that%20thread) seem interesting too but one more time datatype are not automatically managed and should be done individually since column can contains `"`, newline and so on

i take a look in `XMLAgg` and can be used to speed up string concatenation removing cursor and `listagg` character limits:

```
SELECT RTRIM (
      XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, NAME || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'),
      ',')        
FROM MyTABLE
group by GROUP_COL;
```

but again need a way to make it able to manage any kind of data

With SQL Server it was much easier since system mail sender accept a query as parameter and automatically convert it to csv and send as attachment, in Oracle I still didn't find a similar solution.

**EDIT**

Best solution I am searching is a modular function that can be called with different query, so column should be concatenated dynamically, without having to specify them one by one

**EDIT2**

This is more or less what I am looking for:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DatabaseMailAlertProfile',
@recipients = '********@gmail.com',
@query = 'SELECT Sno,Name,Age,code FROM Student,
@subject = 'Student Registrations',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

**@query = 'SELECT Sno,Name,Age,code FROM Student,**

All managed by SQL Server

Comment: SELECT DESC || ',' || GROUP_COL || ',' || ID || ',' || CreatedDate  
    FROM MyTABLE

Comment: what if DESC contains commas? or a new line? i need a robust solution to manage all sort of character

Comment: From the thread you linked: doesn't the latest post by Justin Cave solves your problem?

Comment: U can use any other field separator like 2 '##'  or separator of your choice, while opening the csv u can pass the field separator info.

Comment: i have to send to csv via mail to end user and they know nothing about separator, they will simply open it with excel expecting that all works fine

Comment: @astentx lol, i find my second link no more working and searching in my browser history didi't find any thread with post by Justin Cave... maybe you have it in your history?

Comment: what sound strange to me is that there are no pre-made function to convert data to string managing different data type and i have to reinvent the wheel writing all logic and thinking about any possible exception to manage

Comment: Use a oracle function on DESC to remove the new line or commas .